# Mysql Trigger to call a java method, its pros and cons?

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I have a requirement to call a Java method once a new record has been inserted in to the DB. I would like to know is it a efficient way to do ? what could be the performance issues as my table expects to hold huge data.

Comment: Add code to your Java.  There is no way for mysql to launch anything outside itself.

Comment: @james as per one of the posts http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger its possible to call a java code